# Migrate to Enterprise Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, installation, versioning

We have basemap with shapefile, now we have purchased ArcGIS 10.2 with server and ArcSDE and Oracle. We want to establish Enterprise level so that multiple users can edit without overwrite the source file.

I want to know how start and how to execute?

Comment: your need to setup versioning http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000t7000000 you need standard or advanced arcgis to use this.

Answer (score 3):

Set up Enterprise Geodatabase

> The Create Enterprise Geodatabase tool creates a database, storage
>   locations, and a database user to be used as the geodatabase
>   administrator and owner of the geodatabase depending on the database
>   management system (DBMS) used. It grants the geodatabase administrator
>   privileges required to create a geodatabase, then creates a
>   geodatabase in the database.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000162000000

Privileges

> Specific privileges must be granted to users based on what they need
>   to do in the Oracle database. Some privileges can be granted to roles,
>   but others have to be granted directly to the user.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002n0000002v000000

Recommend backup

> A database backup is a copy of the database. This copy is used to
>   recover the database or individual datasets in the case of database
>   failure or corruption.
>
> Since much time, effort, and money are usually invested in an
>   organization's data, it is critical that you have a tested recovery
>   plan in place for your geodatabase. A recovery plan includes database
>   backups and a tested recovery strategy.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Database_backup_and_recovery/002n00000051000000/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after doing all the steps can i host this in api(web), can you give me steps to do this.

Comment: ArcGIS server has an API http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/ but depending on licence level can be limited in functionality.